# How can i get the best ending in Bloodborne?

Tags: bloodborne

*Bloodborne* has three different endings but only one is the best ending. Which is the best ending and how do I get it?

Comment: Best ending? Dude the souls games revolve around choice of ending, no ending is better than the other, at least from a gameplay perspective, it is a moral and philosophical choice. However in my opinion, the best ending is the one that is most challenging, in that case you need to deny Gehrman and fight him then fight the moon presence. To do so I think you need to collect the three Umbilical Cords of the 4 available in-game and consume them.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on you.

- Do you want the ending where you want to wake up from the nightmare? Don't fight the penultimate boss, and accept his offer.
- Do you want the undeniably worst ending? Don't accept the penultimate boss's offer when you don't have three Umbilical Cords.
- Do you want to see the nightmare to the very end? Don't accept the penultimate boss's offer when you have three Umbilical Cords.

Personally I think the first ending is the best.

Comment: Nice answer, but OP is asking for the content you have put in spoilers. If the spoiler is directly being asked for, there is no reason so hide the answer behind spoiler text. If a user clicks on "How do I get the ending", they should expect to see spoilers on how to get the ending.